# Importing Unity Assets from Mac to Windows

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, import, assets

I am just starting out with Unity and there are some assets that I am trying to import, however, they are for Mac. When I do import them I get an error:
`Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package UnityEditor.Web.JSProxyMgr:DoTasks()`
I am not sure how to import them or if there is a trick to it.
I had a friend with a Mac who was able to open it and copy it to my machine, with no dramas.

Answer (score 0):

Hi DarcyParsley this might have what you're looking for.

[There's multiple reasons as to why this is happening. Here they look at a few.](https://proceduralworlds.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/33000216286-failed-to-import-package-with-error-couldn-t-decompress-package)

> From our support experience, a list of things to check for are:
>
> 1. Does your target disk have enough space to decompress the package?
>    **FIX**: Create more space on your target disk - you need at least twice
>    the free space of the original package for this to complete properly.
> 2. Does your Unity Project or UnityPackage exist in a directory with
>    non-English characters in it? **FIX**: Remove the non english characters
>    in that directory.
> 3. Do you have read\write access to the UnityPackage, its parent
>    directory, and your Unity Project's directory? **FIX**: Assign yourself
>    read / write permissions to these directories.
> 4. Are you sure the download is not corrupt? Sometimes it can happen that
>    the downloaded file gets corrupted or is incomplete. If you have 7zip
>    installed on your computer (note there are unofficial download options
>    for Mac & Linux as well) , you could test this theory by opening the
>    unitypackage file on your computer. You can find the  package files in
>    the following directory:
>
>    Windows: %APPDATA%\Unity\Asset Store-5.x (hidden folder!) Mac:
>    ~/Library/Unity/Asset Store-5.x/ Linux: ~/.local/share/unity3d/Asset
>    Store-5.x
>
>    If 7zip shows you an error or an empty package when opening it, then
>    the package is corrupt and needs to be re-downloaded. To do so, please
>    delete this file and download it again from the asset store. We are
>    aware that this sounds like an unlikely solution to this issue, but we
>    are getting this issue reported about once per week and a simple
>    redownload is often the solution.
> 5. In combination with the "corrupt download" issue, we had reports of
>    security software such as Malwarebytes causing the download
>    corruption. If a simple redownload still results in a corrupt
>    download, it might be worth to consider deactivating additional
>    software that might influence / scan downloads during the download
>    until the installation is finished.